# Jquery Validation - Include minimum requirement if other field is

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I currently have two fields only be required if either one of them is filled in. That is working fine, but what is troublesome is adding a minimum to #minimumField only if the other is filled in. As the following code stands, the minimum error message is firing whether #otherField is filled in or not.

How do I get this minimum only be necessary when otherField is filled in?

```
otherField: {
    required: function(element){
        return $("#minimumField").val()!="0";
    }
},

minimumField: {
    required: function(element){
        return $("#otherField").val()!="";
    },
    min: 0.01
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Got it to now fire at the right time, but how do I specify the minimum amount? It's defaulting to 1, but I want it to be 0.01.

```
minimumField: {
    min: function(element){
        return $("#otherField").val()!="";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: Got it to now fire at the right time, but how do I specify the minimum amount? It's defaulting to 1, but I want it to be 0.01.

```
minimumField: {
    min: function(element){
        return $("#otherField").val()!="";
    }
}
```

That is because your `return` is evaluating a boolean...

```
return $("#otherField").val() != "";
```

`$("#otherField").val() != ""` will always return `true` or `false`, which is why you see the minimum value as `1` (`true`).

If you want the minimum value to be `0.01`, then you must `return` this value...

```
minimumField: {
    min: function(element){
        if ($("#otherField").val() != "") {
            return 0.01; // min set to '0.01'
        } else {
            return '';  // no min value set
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the custom `:filled` selector provide by the plugin...

```
minimumField: {
    min: function(element) {
        if ($("#otherField").is(":filled")) {
            return 0.01; // min set to '0.01'
        } else {
            return '';  // no min value set
        }
    }
}
```

And the same using a ternary operator...

```
minimumField: {
    min: function(element) {
        return ($("#otherField").is(":filled")) ? 0.01 : '';
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/j11zoap7/](http://jsfiddle.net/j11zoap7/)**